# Multiple SQL running two queries then querying the result for one result

Tags: sql-server

I have 1 table with user records on multiple lines. I'm trying to find out who changed their PIN and who did not.

I imported the table into ACCESS and I can create the result I'm looking for in 3 queries. I want to redo these 3 queries into one on the SQL server.

Query 1:

```
SELECT [dbo].[USER].USERNAME 
FROM [dbo].[USER]
WHERE [dbo].[USER].SYSTEMNAME NOT LIKE 'DOMAIN/$SPARE' 
  AND [dbo].[USER].TYPE LIKE 'voice'
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT [dbo].[USER].[USERNAME], [dbo].[USER].[KEYNAME], [dbo].[USER].[STRINGVALUE]
FROM [dbo].[USER]
WHERE [dbo].[USER].TYPE = 'PIN_UPDATED')
```

The third query which will return the final result:

```
SELECT 
    [query1].[USERNAME], [query2].[USERNAME], 
    [query2].[KEYNAME], [query2].[STRINGVALUE]
FROM 
    [query1] 
LEFT JOIN 
    [query2] ON [query1].USERNAME = [query2].USERNAME
```

Using UNION, INNER JOIN and others I get different types of errors with no results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be interested to know what your queries looked like and what errors, but here is one potential way, using CTE:

```
;WITH Query1 AS
(
    SELECT  [USERNAME] 
    FROM    [dbo].[USER] 
    WHERE   [dbo].[USER].SYSTEMNAME NOT LIKE    'DOMAIN/$SPARE' 
    AND     [dbo].[USER].[TYPE]     LIKE        'voice'
)
,Query2 AS
(
    SELECT  [USERNAME]          , 
            [KEYNAME]           , 
            [STRINGVALUE] 
    FROM    [dbo].[USER] 
    WHERE   [dbo].[USER].[TYPE] =   'PIN_UPDATED'
)
SELECT      Q1.[USERNAME]       , 
            Q2.[USERNAME]       , 
            Q2.[KEYNAME]        , 
            Q2.[STRINGVALUE] 
FROM        [Query1] AS Q1
LEFT JOIN   [query2] AS Q2      ON Q1.USERNAME = Q2.USERNAME;
```

Comment: Your code worked! Got my result I will use this as a template for further multiple queries.

Comment: I want to add a time > than 30 days but my query is not accepted by the SQL

Comment: my query was changed to have:

Comment: ;WITH Query1 AS
(
    SELECT  [USERNAME] 
    FROM    [dbo].[USER] 
    WHERE   [dbo].[USER].SYSTEMNAME NOT LIKE    'DOMAIN/$SPARE' 
    AND     [dbo].[USER].[TYPE]     LIKE        'voice'
)
,Query2 AS
(
    SELECT  [USERNAME]          , 
            [KEYNAME]           , 
            [STRINGVALUE] 
    FROM    [dbo].[USER] 
    WHERE   [dbo].[USER].[TYPE] =   'PIN_UPDATED'
)

Comment: SELECT      Q1.[USERNAME]       , 
            Q2.[USERNAME]       , 
            Q2.[KEYNAME]        , 
            Q2.[STRINGVALUE] ,
            SUBSTRING [Q2].[STRINGVALUE], 1, PATINDEX('% UTC', [Q2].[STRINGVALUE]) ) AS DATETIME
FROM        [Query1] AS Q1
LEFT JOIN   [query2] AS Q2      ON Q1.USERNAME = Q2.USERNAME;

I want to add:
WHERE DATETIME > DATEADD(DD, -30, GETDATE())

Comment: @auldh ask a new question pal

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT u1.USERNAME,u2.[KEYNAME], u2.[STRINGVALUE]
FROM [dbo].[USER] AS u1
LEFT JOIN [dbo].[USER] AS u2 ON u1.USERNAME=u2.USERNAME AND u2.TYPE Like 'PIN_UPDATED'
WHERE u1.SYSTEMNAME Not Like 'DOMAIN/$SPARE' AND u1.TYPE Like 'voice'
```